# Limits with the cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology, limits

Show that the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n=(-1)^n$ has no limit in $\mathbb R$ with the cofinite topology.

Further, let $T$ be the topology on $\mathbb R$ in which the open sets are $\emptyset$ together with those $U \subset \mathbb R$ such that $1 \in U$. Show that in $(\mathbb R, T)$, the sequence $(x_n)$ from above has a unique limit $-1$.

I am having difficulty understanding how to prove limits existence under topology, and looking for help or pointed in the right direction for this question.

I have the cofinite topology defined as the topology in which the closed sets are X itself, and the finite subsets of X.

Answer (score 0):

In a topological space $(X,\tau)$, a sequence $(x_n) \in {}^{\mathbf N}\!X$ is said to converge to $x\in X$, iff for all open sets $U \in \tau$ containing $x$, there is $N \in \mathbf N$ such that $x_n \in U$ for $n \ge N$.

So, in the confinite topology, given $x \in \mathbf R\setminus \{1\}$, consider the open set $U = \mathbf R\setminus \{1\} \ni x$. As infinitely many $x_n \not\in U$, $x$ is not a limit of $(x_n)$. For $x = 1$ consider $U = R\setminus \{-1\} \ni 1$ and argue along the same line. Hence, our sequence has no limit in $(\mathbf R, \tau_{\mathrm{cofinite}})$.

For the second example, I'll only give a hint: If $x \ne -1$, Then $U = \mathbf R\setminus \{-1\}$ is an open (why?) set containing $x$ such that infinitely many $x_n$ fall outside of $U$.

If - on the other hand - $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $-1$, then $U$ contains (why?) both $-1$ and(!) $1$, hence all $x_n$, therefore...